# Twisted protocol that simultaneously handles TCP and UDP at once

Tags: python, python-2.7, tcp, udp, twisted

What I want to do, thinking about my logic, is independent of the transport that I choose - I want UDP and TCP to work. Normally, if I was doing TCP or SSL -- this is a little trivial. However, with UDP (no factory) and TCP (uses factory), it becomes a little tricky?

```
from twisted.internet.protocol import Factory, ServerFactory, Protocol, DatagramProtocol
from twisted.internet import reactor

class SpecialServerProtocol(DatagramProtocol, Protocol):
  def datagramReceived(self, datagram, address):
    print("Received udp")
    self.transport.write(datagram, address)

  def dataReceived(self, data):
    print("Received tcp")
    self.transport.write(data)

class SpecialServerFactory(ServerFactory):
  protocol = IPBusServerProtocol

def main():
  reactor.listenTCP(8000, SpecialServerFactory())
  reactor.listenUDP(8000, SpecialServerProtocol())

  reactor.run()

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

This is some code I've managed to get and it seems to work as expected (I think). It's not clear to me if this is actually a good thing to do, or if I should separate out the same logic from TCP/UDP and pass it off to a series of functions independent of how they're called.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TCP is connection-oriented, which means you get a notification that a connection is beginning, when data arrives on it, and when it ends.  UDP is not; you just get chunks of data from various peers, which may appear or disappear at any time with no notification.  Therefore you cannot speak the *same* protocol over TCP and UDP; you need a UDP version and a TCP version.